# How do get a view from a view that has another view controller with a view

Tags: ios, objective-c, computer-science, mobile-development

I am able to manipulate the content of ViewControllerA that has ViewA. I do not want to edit the content of ViewControllerB for a couple of reasons.

Under my view hierarchy, ViewA contains ViewControllerB which has ViewB. How do I get viewB. If I get it, I'd like to resize it which I can do but I can't seem to get it.

This current code gives me viewA.

```
ViewA = ViewControllerA.view
```

How do I get ViewB?

Comment: Your desription says `ViewControllerA` has attribute `ViewA`, which has property `ViewControllerB`, which has attribute `ViewB`.  If so, finding `ViewB` is simple.  Probably your description is wrong.  Please verify and update.

Comment: how ViewControllerB's view got into ViewA hierarchy? do you have access to ViewControllerB.view?

Comment: So viewcontroller B is a child of view controller A.

Comment: Please share the code how you set up `ViewControllerB` and `ViewB`.

Comment: Okay, `ViewControllerB` is a subclass of `ViewControllerA`, so what are you trying to do?  You should show your code or explain in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Hey sorry for the confusion here but what I was doing was actually a little more complicated than this. I was adding a view controller that had several layers of view controllers and views as a childViewController to my view controller. This created quite a complex hierarchy such that just simply getting the view from the childviewcontroller,viewcontrollerB, inside my viewcontrollerA and resizing the part that I wanted inside this view controlleraA wasn't working. My only option was to edit the content of viewControllerB itself, which I didn't want to do at first, to assume the size of the parent view controller A's view.

Made a new method inside viewcontrollerB with this code

```
childViewController.view.frame = _owner.view.bounds;
[childViewController.view setNeedsLayout];
```